# How do I call another program in Cobol?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm developing a system in Cobol using screen section and I can't call a customer registration program when I select an option in the menu that I created in another program. I am using opencobol with GnuCOBOL compiler.

```
CALL "ANOTHER-PROGRAM"
     USING BY CONTENT SUBMENU-IN-WS
CANCEL "ANOTHER-PROGRAM"
```

which I get this error:

> libcob: module "ANOTHER-PROGRAM" not found.

How do I call another program in Cobol using **opencobol**? Do I need to use linkage section in the `ANOTHER-PROGRAM` even than I will not use it?

Comment: Is this question answered for you? If yes please mark the answer as "accepted" (= worked for you), otherwise clarify what is missing so we may could add to it.

Answer (score 6):

`CALL` is perfectly fine. You only have to make sure that `ANOTHER-PROGRAM` is available in `COB_LIBRARY_PATH` (environment variable, defaults to ".") and that both the dso name (.so / .dll) matches "ANOTHER-PROGRAM" or that this dso was named in `COB_PRE_LOAD`.

Note: OpenCOBOL will only find it if the original `PROGRAM-ID` in "ANOTHER-PROGRAM" is named exactly the same (including case).